# Preventing Docker Compose container from creating files as root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.13.0

ENV WORK_DIR=/app
RUN mkdir -p ${WORK_DIR}
WORKDIR ${WORK_DIR}

RUN mkdir ${WORK_DIR}/data
RUN chmod -R 755 ${WORK_DIR}/data

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  fetch:
    container_name: fetch
    build: .
    command: sh -c "npx prisma migrate deploy && npm start"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data:z
```

The container fetches new files and saves them into a directory configured by the app running in the container, defaulting to data/. The issue is that they're all created as root and cannot be manipulated by the host. If I chown the dir on the host, it works, but any new files are then created as root again.

I've tried a couple different variations of creating a new user in Dockerfile and passing host user info into the compose file but it always seems to result in a disconnect between the Dockerfile and compose file. I'm trying to keep things as easy as `docker compose up`, if possible.

Comment: The main container process is running as root unless you tell it something different, and so it will create files as root.  If you're trying to use a host directory to store the data, the container needs to run as the same user that owns the directory.  I've written up a recipe for that in [Docker: non-root user does not have writing permissions when using volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349101/docker-non-root-user-does-not-have-writing-permissions-when-using-volumes/66350210#66350210); does that setup help you?

Comment: I'm trying to keep things as simple as `docker compose up` rather than using docker run etc. I do believe this would work if I wasn't using compose?

Comment: You'd hit the same problem.  Compose `user:` is equivalent to `docker run -u` in my linked answer, except that it can't run the shell substitution, so you need to run `id -u` on the host and then put that specific numeric `user: 1000`.

Comment: Alright, so it seems I have a disconnect between the Dockerfile and compose file then? Since I need to use compose to bring up postgres as well.
I basically need the Dockerfile to create a non-root user, create the dir that the volume requires, then have compose run the container as that same user.

Doing that with your user creation Dockerfile commands results in my node app erroring with `EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/myuser'`, and the data/ dir still gets created as root.

Comment: The volume mount will hide everything in that directory, including its ownership and permissions.  There's not usually a requirement to "create the user" _per se_ so long as the main container process is running with the right numeric user ID.

Comment: I think I've sorted it by creating data/ on the host and ensuring it's part of vcs by adding an ignore file in there, then setting `user: node` as the node images have that user. Thanks for the help.